# Capatalize every other letter... 

Tags: php, uppercase, lowercase

How would i capitalize every other letter in a string? I know how to convert to lower or upper or the first, etc but not sure how to go about every other. To be clear I've included examples. Also this is for creating a cipher my son and i are messing around with, i would never format regular text in this fashion.

```
pizza -> PiZzA
party -> PaRtY
popcorn -> PoPcOrN
```

Comment: +1 for including examples and a pretty clear explanation. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$newStr = '';
foreach(str_split($str) as $index => $char) {
    $newStr .= ($index % 2) ? strtolower($char) : strtoupper($char);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/moUlv3y3).

Comment: Quick explanation to what's going on: he's using an in-line conditional (that's the `?` statement) to check whether or not the position is even or not. If it's even, capitalize it - else make sure it's lower case. Good luck! Good response. +1

Comment: @Ryan No worries, just make sure you keep it to you and your son :)

Comment: @Alex Do you know if the same concept would be possible with an array? I'm exploding quotes running the capital conversion and imploding them back, however obviously str_split expects a string.

Sorry about the pings, moving code to main question.

Comment: @Ryan `foreach()` is an array iterator, so just pass the array straight to it. I converted the string into an array with `str_split()`, so `foreach()` wouldn't complain.

Comment: @Alex Im new enough to programming to have that go over my head, do you see where im making a mistake in my added code?

Comment: @Ryan Just remove the `str_split()` function that you pass to `foreach()` and you should be good. So it should look like `foreach($arr as ...)`.

Comment: @Alex, i tried that and while it doesn't present any errors it doesn't seem make any changes... Any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan May need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I will try something like this:

```
$string = join(
    array_map(
        function($s){
            return ucfirst($s);
        },
        str_split($string,2)
    )
);
```

or, as one-liner:

```
$string = join(array_map(function($s){return ucfirst($s);}, str_split($string,2)));
```

You can generalize the function passing as parameter the length of chunk to be capitalized
and letting the function do the work. The algorithm is straightforward:

- str_split return an array of strings of the desired length,
- the array_map function add the transformation to the chunks and
- the join glues together the strings into the result string.

The final function is:

```
function camelCycles($string, $period) {
  return join(
     array_map(
       function($s){
         return ucfirst($s);
       },
       str_split($string, $period)
     )
  );
}
```

It use only native constructs and thus should be quite fast.

EDIT:

A function that doesn't use lambda and therefore suitable for PHP 5.0 and onward, as str_split was introduced with the php5 release

```
function camelCycles($string, $span) {
  return join(array_map('ucfirst', str_split(strtolower($string), $span)));
}
```

Comment: +1 for doing it different. Note that people need >= PHP 5.3 for this to work. Also, you could drop the `''` argument to `join()` and it will be even shorter :)

Comment: @alex you know, I'm doing a lot of javascript and lambdas are springing everywhere, expecially when they are not needed. Good point for the join hint, I will apply it

Comment: That new one is very sexy. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would split it as an array and then reattach it together:

```
function strtoupper_lower($str){
     $temp = explode('',$str);
     $return = '';
     foreach($temp as $i=>$val){
         if($i%1 == 0) $return .= strtolower($val);
         else $return .= strtolower($val);
     } 
     return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function spasticafy($st)
{
    $r = '';
    $n = false;

    foreach(str_split($st) as $i)
    {
        $r .= ($n ? strtoupper($i) : $i);
        $n = !$n;
    }

    return $r;
}

echo spasticafy("hello there, mr person sir");
```